# Autohotkey doesn't check if statement condition

Tags: autohotkey

My script should check for the value of a variable, if it's `0`, it should remap some keys, if the value is not `0`, it should not remap any key, or run any of the hotkeys: (my variable is called `chatbox`)

```
#IfWinActive Minecraft 1.8.9
  If (ChatBox = 0){
    1::z
  }
#IfWinActive
```

But it doesn't work! AHK doesn't check the variable:

```
---- C:\Users\...\mysimplescript.ahk
157: SPI_SETDEFAULTINPUTLANG := 0x005A
157: SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE := 2
030: Return (3.41)
263: Send,z (0.02)
263: Return (2.50)
```

Why don't I use the `if` statement inside the hotkey? I did! the problem is, it doesn't really work with games, it's just probably how Windows works, I tried this:

```
1::
  If (ChatBox = 0)
    send z
  else
    send 1
return
```

I don't want to use an `if` statement inside a hotkey, my question is, I want certain hotkeys to get activated with change of a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This conditionally executes a hotkey based on a variable:**

```
#If ChatBox = 0
  1::z
#If
```

**This conditionally executes a hotkey based on a variable and window:**

```
#If WinActive("Minecraft 1.8.9") and ChatBox = 0
  1::z
#If
```

REF: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm